# Basis of Ker f and Im f

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear application as following

$$
f\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(x-y,y-x,0\right)
$$

I found that a basis of Ker$f$ is $\left(1,1,0\right)$ and that a basis of Im$f$ is $\left(1,-1,0\right)$. But by rank theorem we should have
$$
\dim(\operatorname{Im} f)+\dim(\operatorname{Ker} f)=3
$$

but here I've found two spaces with dimension 1, what am I missing ?

Comment: The Kernel also consists of (0,0,1) and hence its basis is (1,1,0), (0,0,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the kernel wrong. $(0,0,1)$ is also in the kernel.

Comment: Ah yeah obviously --', thanks